# OSM doesn't show in Android 5.1 but is shown in Android 4.1.1, How i can resolve it?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, leaflet, openstreetmap

i'm developing an hybrid app with cordova using leafletjs and osm. The open street map is shown in android 4.1.1 but not in android 5 (it shows gray panel). How i can resolve it?

[image: on Andorid 5.1 (CyanogenMod 12.1)]

[image: on Andorid 4.1.1]

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** following below comments

In addition to the Cordova whitelist, it looks like you also need to explicitly set your [Content-Security-Policy](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/#content-security-policy) (CSP) in your page HTML Head.

Probably something like:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' *.tile.osm.org">
```

See also: https://content-security-policy.com/

Note: from your error log, it looks like you should also allow other sources.

---

Have you white listed the `openstreetmap.org` website (with subdomains)?
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/guide/appdev/whitelist/index.html

Comment: yes, i give permission to all domains, as you can see from image.
thank you

Comment: Without further details from your side, I am afraid it is impossible to provide you with more support...

Comment: What does the Chrome inspect remote debug tool gives you?

Comment: Thank you for the log. I have edited the above answer, it should solve your issue now.

Comment: @max91r have you solved your issue? Please provide some feedback so that other people who may face the same problem know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
//onde mostra a imagem do mapa
Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
Configuration.getInstance().load(ctx, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx));
```

Use is code within on create